# Records are not being written to kafka cluster even though job runs successfully. spark/pyspark/databricks/

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, kafka-producer-api

I am currently working on the use case where I read the csv data from `S3 bucket` and storing it in the dataframes and then write each partition into `confluent-kafka cluster`. I am writing the notebook in the databricks platform.

example code -

```
    def readFromS3():
    csvDf = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("s3a://xx-xx-xx-xx/staging4")
    return csvDf
  

from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
def writeToKafkaUsingKafkaProducer():
  dataframe = readFromS3()
  dataframe.show(10)
  #write Each partition into Kafka Topic
  def getEvent(row):
    return json.dumps({
      "value": {
        "restaurant_id": row["RESTAURANT_ID"],
        "customer_id": row["CUSTOMER_ID"],
        "dt": row["DT"],
      }
    })

  def write_data(partition):
    kafka_config = {}
    kafka_brokers = "xx.aws.confluent.cloud:9092"
    security_name = "SASL_SSL"
    security_mechanism = "PLAIN"
    user_name = "xx"
    password = "xx"
    topic_name = "test_topic"
    kafka_config.update({'bootstrap_servers': kafka_brokers})
    kafka_config.update({'security_protocol': security_name})
    kafka_config.update({'sasl_mechanism': security_mechanism})
    kafka_config.update({'sasl_plain_username': user_name})
    kafka_config.update({'sasl_plain_password': password})
    producer = KafkaProducer(**kafka_config)
    for row in partition:
      message = getEvent(row)
      producer.send(topic_name, message.encode("utf-8"))
    producer.flush()
    producer.close()
  dataframe.rdd.foreachPartition(write_data)    
  
writeToKafkaUsingKafkaProducer()
```

Getting no error in the driver logs. But not able to see any data in the topic in the dashboard.

```
2021-05-07T16:45:51.237+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 262144K->35839K(407040K)] 326409K->122724K(566784K), 0.0473319 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.04, real=0.05 secs] 
2021-05-07T17:06:07.155+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 407039K->38840K(451584K)] 493924K->125733K(611328K), 0.0347280 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.02, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-05-07T17:32:18.031+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 437176K->49537K(498688K)] 524069K->136438K(658432K), 0.0452769 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.04, real=0.05 secs] 
2021-05-07T17:32:18.144+0000: [GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 65590K->41246K(505856K)] 152490K->128147K(665600K), 0.0289151 secs] [Times: user=0.04 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs] 
2021-05-07T17:32:18.173+0000: [Full GC (Metadata GC Threshold) [PSYoungGen: 41246K->0K(505856K)] [ParOldGen: 86900K->113841K(219136K)] 128147K->113841K(724992K), [Metaspace: 53351K->53351K(1095680K)], 0.1440773 secs] [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.01, real=0.14 secs] 
2021-05-07T17:33:07.671+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 441344K->24567K(708096K)] 555185K->138416K(927232K), 0.0423801 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.02, real=0.04 secs] 
2021-05-07T18:15:23.685+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 668151K->26076K(706560K)] 782000K->139933K(925696K), 0.0667142 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.02, real=0.07 secs]
```

**Any help would be appreciated.**

Comment: why aren't you using the just `dataframe.write.format("kafka")....` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt size of the dataframe is so big. I can't do that since doing this would affect the existing cluster.

Comment: existing kafka cluster I mean

Comment: I don’t understand what will be the difference in that case. You are doing the same but ineffective way

Comment: @AlexOtt : Okay. Let's consider I write using the way you are suggesting. Then how would I pass the security_protocol, and mechanism in the param map? using option?

Comment: just follow documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#security

Comment: @AlexOtt would it be possible for you to write an answer for this one? I was not able to follow up with the official documentation.